# Package not found after pip install

Tags: python, pip

I've published a module to PyPi using Flit: [a2d_diary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/a2d_diary/0.1) (I've checked that the tar.gz contains all the scripts).

Then, I tried to install it in a virtual env in Windows and Linux using `pip install a2d_diary` and although it works and all dependencies are installed, if I try to run `a2d_diary` in a terminal (with the venv activate) it does not find my package.

Is this a problem with Flit, PyPi or am I missing something in the main script? The source code is [here](https://github.com/JulioV/parkinsons-self-reporting/tree/master/src)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `a2d_diary.py` is installed, but it won't be accessible via running `$ ad2_diary.py` from your terminal. These are the package files that were installed:

```
$ pip show -f a2d_diary
Name: a2d-diary
Version: 0.1
Summary: A2D-Diary web app. Create and encode paper diaries 
automatically
Home-page: https://a2d-diary.netlify.com
Author: Julio Vega
Author-email: julio.vega@protonmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: PyPDF2, numpy, waitress, opencv-python, reportlab, falcon-multipart, falcon, Pillow
Files:
  __pycache__/a2d_diary.cpython-36.pyc
  a2d_diary-0.1.dist-info/INSTALLER
  a2d_diary-0.1.dist-info/LICENSE
  a2d_diary-0.1.dist-info/METADATA
  a2d_diary-0.1.dist-info/RECORD
  a2d_diary-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
  a2d_diary.py
```

If you want the script to be executable after the installation, you have to declare it as such in the package setup file (btw, I don't see any `setup.py` in your repository - did you commit it?). Example `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='a2d_diary',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={
        '': 'src',
    },
    scripts=['src/a2d_diary.py'],
)
```

Another thing you will need in order to make your `a2d_diary.py` script executable is the shebang line (works for Unix, no idea what to do on Windows since I don't do Windows at all): first line in `a2d_diary.py` should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

if your script can be run with any version of Python or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

for Python 3 specifically or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

for Python 2 specifically.

Now, if you build a wheel or source tar and install it, you will be able to run the script via

```
$ a2d_diary.py
```

Comment: It worked thanks, and windows worked without a specific shebang